# Display an array item's data based on the radio button that's being selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display the shoe array item's data if the color property matches the radio button color that is clicked. If the black radio button is selected, the array item with the black color property value should show.

(Note: How can I display or render the shoe data)

Thanks in advance!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class CheckColor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      color: '',
      shoes: [
        {name: 'Black Shoe', color: 'Black', price: 180},
        {name: 'Red Shoe', color: 'Red', price: 120},
        {name: 'White Shoe', color: 'White', price: 100}
      ]
    }

    this.handleColorChange = this.handleColorChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleColorChange(e) {
    const color = e.target.value
    this.setState({ color: color })
  }

  render() {
    const colors = ['Black', 'Red', 'White']
    return(
      <form>
        {colors.map((color, index) => 
          <label key={index}>
            {color}
            <input 
            value={color}
            checked={this.state.color === color}
            onChange={this.handleColorChange}
            type="radio"
            />
          </label>
        )}
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CheckColor />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the colors based on the selected color values and then just use a map for showing the filtered shoes.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class CheckColor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: "",
      shoes: [
        { name: "Black Shoe", color: "Black", price: 180 },
        { name: "Red Shoe", color: "Red", price: 120 },
        { name: "White Shoe", color: "White", price: 100 }
      ]
    };

    this.handleColorChange = this.handleColorChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleColorChange(e) {
    const color = e.target.value;
    console.log(color);
    this.setState({ color: color });
  }

  render() {
    const colors = ["Black", "Red", "White"];
    const shoesToShow = this.state.shoes.filter(item => ( item.color === this.state.color));
    console.log(shoesToShow);
    return (
      <>
        <form>
          {colors.map((color, index) => (
            <label key={index}>
              {color}
              <input
                value={color}
                checked={this.state.color === color}
                onChange={this.handleColorChange}
                type="radio"
              />
            </label>
          ))}
        </form>
        {shoesToShow.map(shoe => (
          <div>{shoe.name} </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologize. I wasn't aware of that feature or its importance. Its accepted. Pretty new to posting.. Thanks again my friend.

Comment: if I am using a color in state, while color.map is called, is it possible to update the state with currently selected color ??

Answer (score 1):

Four Steps to display object as input radio dynamically
// 1.  obj data

```
   const phoneNums = {
        jim: {
            type: "Mobile",
            value: 4153662323
        },
        tim: {
            type: "Business",
            value: 4153662323
        },
       
    }
    //2. convert obj to array
    const radioNumArr = Object.keys(phoneNums).map(i => phoneNums[i]);
            
    // 3. Set data to User State via Hook
    setRadioData(radioNumArr );

   // 4.set hook and loop on radiodata
   const [radioData, setRadioData] = useState([]);
    <div>
                    {radioData.map((option) => (
                        <div className="forminputlabel" >
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                name="dynamic-radio"
                                value={option.value}

                            />
                            <label>{option.type}  </label>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```